# Adding Javascript file into Expression Engine

Tags: javascript, html, expressionengine

For the life of me I cannot get a javascript file to load / be added correctly to an expression Template file (Ie.: _footer)

I've tried all these and nothing.

`<script src="{base_url}/scripts/main"></script>`

`<script src="{base_url}/scripts/main.js"></script>`

`<script src="{base_path}/scripts/main.js"></script>`

Thank you for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you check out this article which goes about explaining how to set up templates, including partials, layout etc. It says it all far better than I could.

[Templating Intro (ExpressionEngine University)](https://u.expressionengine.com/course/introduction-to-building-an-expressionengine-site/templating-intro-templates-template-groups-staying-dry)

To answer your question though, you want to use the site_url variable.

```
<script src="{site_url}/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up pointing to it that way.

Comment: I did more research into this, and found the proper solution for you. The answer has been updated to reflect the change.